# Parsing JSON into a object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse this JSON using gson:

```
{"hvs1":{"16191":[["TestFile3","C",["A"]],["TestFile3","-",["1G","1A"]]],"16193":[["TestFile3","C",["G"]]]},"hvs2":{"25":[["TestFile3","-",["1A"]]]},"outros":{"16423":[["TestFile3","A",["T"]]]}}
```

Into this object

```
public class Results {

private String regiaoAfetada;
private String posicaoReferencia;
private String nomeDoArquivo;
private String baseAlteradaReferencia;
private List<String> mutacaoEncontrada;

//get and set

}
```

And my test class to try to achive this, but I'm getting a error.

```
public class JsonTeste {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("foobar.json")) {

        Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, TreeMap>>() {
        }.getType();

        TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, List<List<List<String>>>>> map = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

        List<Results> listaMutacoes = new ArrayList<Results>();

        for (Entry<String, TreeMap<String, List<List<List<String>>>>> regioesMap : map.entrySet()) {

            TreeMap<String, List<List<List<String>>>> regiaoUm = regioesMap.getValue();

            for (Entry<String, List<List<List<String>>>> regiaoUmResult : regiaoUm.entrySet()) {

                List<List<List<String>>> resultados = regiaoUmResult.getValue();

                for (List<List<String>> list : resultados) {

                    Results resultado = new Results();
                    resultado.setRegiaoAfetada(regioesMap.getKey());
                    resultado.setPosicaoReferencia(regiaoUmResult.getKey());
                    resultado.setNomeDoArquivo(list.get(0).toString());
                    resultado.setBaseAlteradaReferencia(list.get(1).toString());
                    resultado.setMutacaoEncontrada(list.get(2));
                    listaMutacoes.add(resultado);
                }
            }
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

The problem is when I try to parse this part

```
 [
         "TestFile3",
         "-",
         [
           "1G",
           "1A"
         ]
       ]
```

Because I have two Strings and a Array inside, so the problem Is when I try to place "TestFile3" into setNomeDoArquivo, but even if I comment this line, i get the same error in the second line.

resultado.setNomeDoArquivo(list.get(0).toString());
                        resultado.setBaseAlteradaReferencia(list.get(1).toString());

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List

Can you guys help me?

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you can indicate which line of your code triggered the exception (hint: look at the stack trace)

Comment: I edited the question and put there.

Comment: You've copy/pasted two lines of code - the exception can't be happening at both of those lines.

Comment: Well, I edited again with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The List `resultados` is of `List<string>` or `List<List<String>>`.When you get the item of `resultados` it can be one of them. So to generalized declare it as `List<List<Object>>`**

Try The below Code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try (Reader reader = new FileReader("foobar.json")) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<TreeMap<String, TreeMap>>() {
    }.getType();

    TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, List<List<Object>>>> map = gson.fromJson(reader, type);

    List<Results> listaMutacoes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<String, List<List<Object>>>> regioesMap : map.entrySet()) {

        TreeMap<String, List<List<Object>>> regiaoUm = regioesMap.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<Object>>> regiaoUmResult : regiaoUm.entrySet()) {

            List<List<Object>> resultados = regiaoUmResult.getValue();

            for (List<Object> list : resultados) {

                System.out.println(list);

                Results resultado = new Results();
                resultado.setRegiaoAfetada(regioesMap.getKey());
                resultado.setPosicaoReferencia(regiaoUmResult.getKey());
                resultado.setNomeDoArquivo((String) list.get(0));
                resultado.setBaseAlteradaReferencia((String) list.get(1));
                resultado.setMutacaoEncontrada((List<String>) list.get(2));
                listaMutacoes.add(resultado);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```